# tqdm stops showing progress in terminal "... (more hidden) ..."

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tmux, tqdm

I am training a neural network and I found it useful to have a `tqdm` bar showing how many steps in **epoch** has come.

I faced the following problem:

> after reaching the end of a terminal window, it shows `... (more hidden) ...` and I cannot do anything about it. I tried scrolling up
>   and down in tmux, but it does nothing.

The connection to the Linux server is established through ssh and tmux is used inside the dedicated machine. The code for tqdm is:

```
pbar = tqdm(total=4500)
pbar.set_description(f'EPOCH: {epoch}')
pbar.n = *value*
pbar.update()
```

how it looks:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z91Ep.jpg)

Interestingly, tho, that I couldn't find anything connected to "... (more hidden) ..." anywhere in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when there are [more nested bars than lines in the terminal](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/963#issuecomment-624165748).

It [can also happen if you forget to `close()`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/963#issuecomment-624408354) finished progress bars. Using `with` will make sure that the bars are closed eventually:

```py
with tqdm(...) as pbar:
   ...
```